# Accessing index inside *apply

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have two containers, `conty` and `contx`. The values of both are tied to each other. `conty[1]` relates to `contx[1]` etc. while using apply on `contx` I want to access the index inside an apply structure so I can put values from corresponding element in `conty` into `contz` depending upon the index of `x`.

```
lapply(contx, function(x) {
    if (x==1) append(contz,conty[xindex])
})
```

I could easily do this in a `for` loop but everybody insists that using the apply is better. And I tried to look for examples but the only thing I could find was mostly stuff for generating maps where it wasn't entirely clear how I could adapt to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. "everybody insists that using the apply is better".  Sorry, but they're wrong; it's not *necessarily* better. See the old-school [Burns Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) ("If you are using R and you think you’re in hell, this is a map for you"), chapter 4 ("Overvectorization"):

> A common reflex is to use a function in the `apply` family. This is not vectorization, it is loop-hiding. The apply function has a for loop in its definition. The `lapply` function buries the loop, but execution times tend to be roughly equal to an explicit `for` loop ... Base your decision of using an apply function on Uwe’s Maxim (page 20). The issue is of human time rather than silicon chip time. Human time can be wasted by taking longer to write the code, and (often much more importantly) by taking more time to understand subsequently what it does.

However, what you are doing that's bad is *growing an object* (also covered in the *Inferno*).  Assuming that in your example `contz` started as an empty list, this should work (is my example reflective of your use case?)

```
x <- c(1,2,3,1)
conty <- list("a","b","c","d")
contz <- conty[which(x==1)]
```

Alternatively, if you want to use *both* the value and the index in your function, you can write a two-variable function `f(val,index)` and then use `Map(f,my_list,seq_along(my_list))`